# How to modify sobel edge detection to get only closed contour of objects?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlBSWW

I want to filter out all output without closed path so that I can get only outline of the objects in an image. Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.